# How to update react JS state functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-functional-component

How can I change a specific object in a state for example, I have data like this

```
const colors= [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: "red",
      },
      {
        id: 1,
        name: "green",
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: "blue",
      },
    ];

const storage = [{
id:2,
name:"64 GB"
},
{
id:2,
name:"128 GB"
]
```

The state value should be like this `[{id:1, name:'red"}, {id:2,name:"128GB"}]`

Is there any way to update the state based on the id only? For example: I need to loop on the data and if the `state.id === id` it will update that specific object.
So in our example, I need to update the state to be `[{id:1, name:'green"}, {id:2,name:"128GB"}]` if the `state.id === 1`

Thanks in advance

Comment: create new object using `Array.map`

Comment: would you like to update colors or storage? which on is your state?

Comment: both are in my state and i want to update them based on the input data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update your array state of objects with a shallow copy and change the value, same as bellow:

```
import * as React from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [colors, setColors] = React.useState([
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "red"
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "green"
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "blue"
    }
  ]);
  const updateState = (id, name) => {
    let copy = [...colors];
    let color = copy.filter((x) => x.id == id)[0];
    if (!color) return;
    let index = copy.indexOf(color);
    color.name = name;
    copy[index] = color;
    setColors(copy);
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {colors.map((color, index) => (
        <>
          <p>
            {color.id} : {color.name}
          </p>
        </>
      ))}
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          updateState(2, "yellow");
        }}
      >
        update
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit mutable-wildflower-n10ys]

Answer (score 2):

You could always copy the current value in local var, modify and set again the state. Something like:

```
const [colors, setColor] = useState([
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "red",
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "green",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "blue",
  },
]);

...

let colorCopy = Object.assign({}, colors); //<-- make a copy of color
colorCopy = colorCopy.map(x => { 
   if (x.id === 1) x.name = "black";
   return x;
}; // modify name property for id === 1
setColor(colorCopy); //<-- set new state
```

**EDIT**

@Nicolas Menettrier and @andy mccullough raised a good point of discussion: "Why call Object.assign if map function already does a copy of colors array?" This is correct so you could also write above code in this way:

```
let colorCopy = colors.map(x => { 
   if (x.id === 1) x.name = "black";
   return x;
}; // modify name property for id === 1
setColor(colorCopy); //<-- set new state
```

1 line code less.

Comment: Why use `Object.assign({}, colors)` on an array? Why 'make a copy' when `.map` will create a new array anyway and why are you trying to reassign `colorCopy` when it is a `const` ?

Comment: Why not just doing a `color.map` ? It will return a new Array and it will not alter the state

Comment: @NicolasMenettrier @andy Yes, in this case I think we could directly do `let colorCopy = colors.map(...)`